# How to add data to the grouped row in AgGrid's grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When using Row Grouping in AgGrid, how one can add data to the grouped row as follows:

[image: Grouped Row with data]

The result is not an aggregate, actually it should be another value from the group itself, I can use the master detail to achieve that but I couldn't find an easy way of changing the details grid to look like the grouped one.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.